# Which of these expressions is the more correct usage of the SUM() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the sum of some daily volumes multiplied by their list price and a rate, but have noticed I am getting slightly different results depending on how I use the SUM() function.

I've tried multiplying the fields inside of SUM() as well as moving the multiplication outside of the aggregate function.

```
SELECT SUM(Vol * LP * Rate) FROM Table A
-- or
SELECT SUM(Vol) * LP * Rate FROM Table A GROUP BY LP, Rate
```

As these results will get aggregated to a customer, I didn't expect to be concerned about the grouping and still don't see how this could be an issue.

Comment: Since neither is valid as written, and they do different things based on the data, can you show us some sample data, expected results, and some queries that actually work?

Comment: Those two equations are not even close to the same thing. I would be shocked if they would return the same results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are thousands of rows of data and I'm still trying to determine the desired result. I'm looking to know the difference between the two functions

Comment: @SeanLange Clearly I am wrong/confused. That's why I asked. Way to add value though!

Comment: The 1st query (if this is your actual code) returns only 1 row. The 2nd returns as many rows as are the combinations of LP, Rate. So how can they be the same?

Comment: See distributive property of summation. Floating point considerations could come into play especially if the constant terms are not in the same scale. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These do different things, so you should use the version appropriate for your problem.

For the second, you have to include `LP` and `Rate` in the `GROUP BY`.

This is not necessary -- or even desirable -- for the first.

So that is the answer.  Use the version that corresponds to the `GROUP BY` that you want.  I would imagine that this would typically be the first version.

Comment: Forgot to mention - these results get aggregated by customer as well. So, I wasn't worried about the groupings on LP and Rate (which do vary for a product).